# problem with chart js pie chart dataset data

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

[image]

This is the output of the code which I don't want since each data sits inside the other, I followed the documentation and other code examples but to no avail.
here is my code

```
 let labelCharts: string[] = ['Supplier Debt', 'Raw Material Cost', 'Product Cost', 'Customer Debt'];
    let myDoughnutChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
        labels: labelCharts,
        datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
          borderWidth: 10,
          label: 'Supplier Debt',
          data: [1, 5, 1],

        },
        {
          data: rawMatCostArr,
          backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
          borderWidth: 10,
          label: 'Raw Material Cost',
        },
        {
          data: productCostArr,
          backgroundColor: "#3cba9f",
          borderWidth: 10,
          label: 'Product Cost',
        },
        {
          data: agentsDebtArr,
          backgroundColor: "#e8c3b9",
          borderWidth: 10,
          label: 'Customer Debt',
        }
        ]
      },
      options: {

        maintainAspectRatio: false,

        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Total'
        }
      }
    });
```

note that each variable inside the data property is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the behaviour you want you only need 1 dataset and put the sum of the data in it. If you use it like shown in this config you get the desired outcome:

```
const config = {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
        labels: ['Supplier Debt', 'Raw Material Cost', 'Product Cost', 'Customer Debt'],
        datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd","#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9"],
          borderWidth: 10,
          label: 'Supplier Debt',
          data: [1, 5, 3,6],

        }
        ]
      },
      options: {

        maintainAspectRatio: false,

        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Total'
        }
      }
    };
```

[image: Chart as it should be]

You might want to decrease the border with since it will make your chart look a lot better.